# How to fix 'Video play but don't have sound on iOS with expo'

Tags: ios, react-native, video, expo, react-native-video

I use video component from expo. I can play video, but it doesn't sound in iOS. In Android it's okay. How can I fix it.

```
<Video style={{ width: 340, 
                                height: 220,
                                borderRadius: 10, 
                                overflow: 'hidden' }}
                                posterSource={require('../../assets/loading2.gif')}
                                usePoster={true}
                                rate={1.0}
                                isMuted={false}
                                useNativeControls = {true}
                                volume={1.0}
                                playsInSilentLockedModeIOS ={ true }
                                resizeMode='cover' 
                                shouldPlay={true} 
                                source={{uri : url}} />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Determine whether the `media` should continue playing while the `app` is in the `background`. This allows customers to continue listening to the `audio`.

To use this feature on `iOS`, you must:

- [Enable Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3) Audio in your `Xcode` project
- Set the ignoreSilentSwitch prop to `"ignore"`

Comment: But when I play it. It doesn't sound.

Comment: Are you testing with a real cell phone?

Comment: Yes, I test with iOS 12 on Iphone 8 plus.

Answer (score 8):

The audio wasn't working because I had my phone on silent. To change this default behaviour, set `playsInSilentLockedModeIOS={ true }`.

(I know OP already has this in their code, but I'm answering just in case this helps someone).

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a reference (`ref`) to the `<Video />` component.
2. Use a state to listen when the video starts playing.
3. When it does, call `await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ playsInSilentModeIOS: true });`.
4. Immediately after, re-play the video by calling `ref.current.playAsync();`

In summary, my component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Audio, Video as OriginalVideo } from 'expo-av';

const triggerAudio = async (ref) => {
  await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ playsInSilentModeIOS: true });
  ref.current.playAsync();
};

const Video = ({ ...props }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status.isPlaying) triggerAudio(ref);
  }, [ref, status.isPlaying]);

  return (
    <OriginalVideo
      ref={ref}
      onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(status)}
      useNativeControls
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Tested with Expo SDK v45 and iOS 16.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Enabling background audio is not the solution (especially if you are using a managed Expo project where messing with Xcode settings is not ideal). I found that the bug exists when you use `useNativeControls={true}` and do not auto play the video. If you try `shouldPlay={true}` you should see it working. That's not a great solution (auto playing video is very MySpace circa 2005).

I fixed it by putting an overlay over the video screen with a custom play button. For some reason calling play from the video ref uses the correct sound profile.

```
  const videoRef = React.useRef<Video>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const enableAudio = async () => {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
        interruptionModeIOS: INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: false,
        interruptionModeAndroid: INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
        shouldDuckAndroid: false,
      })
    }
    enableAudio()
  }, [])

  const play = () => videoRef.current && videoRef.current.playAsync()

  const poster = (
      <View position="absolute" flexible="column-center" bg="transparent">
        <IconButton
          name="play"
          onPress={play}
          size={72}
          iconSize={72}
          bg="transparent"
          iconColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.9)"
        />
      </View>
    )

  return (
    <View>
      <VideoPlayer
        ref={videoRef}
        source={R.is(String, props.asset) ? { uri: props.asset } : props.asset}
        shouldPlay={props.autoPlay !== false}
        useNativeControls={true}
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
      />
      <View position="absolute" flexible="column-center" bg="transparent">
        <IconButton
          name="play"
          onPress={play}
          size={72}
          iconSize={72}
          bg="transparent"
          iconColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.9)"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: this is insane. i just set it to auto play, and the sound worked correctly. haha!

Comment: @zackify I know ‍♂️

Comment: I am facing the issue that ios video play using expo-av goes muted, whereas android played the sound. can you please elaborate where to add "auto play" and how it works?

Comment: @DolaChakraborty if you want it to auto play (which fixes this issue on iOS) you can set these two props to true: <VideoPlayer useNativeControls={true} and shouldPlay={true} />

Comment: Note that as of Expo 45.0, setting "shouldPlay" to true no longer fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue due to the silent switch on the side of the iPhone being enabled. To have the video player play sound I needed to included the following as a prop to the video component.

```
ignoreSilentSwitch={'ignore'}
```

Comment: this prop is not available in the lib currently